# State of this instance has been externally set to None. Taking the poison pill

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

We are running airflow on kubernetes. Though airflow runs the DAGs without any issues but I see the below weird error messages in the airflow logs.

However, when I check the kubernetes pod logs where the DAG is running, it doesnt have any issues and all the tasks in the DAG completed successfully. Any reason why i'm getting the below error messages in the airflow logs? Also all the logs are not printed in the airflow logs though everything is printed without any error messages in kubernetes pod logs.

Airflow logs is printing the message until a step in the python code is taking more than 1 hr...thats when the airflow logs is stopped writing to a file. Not sure if this is something related to task time out when it runs more than specific time

Please let me know if you have any ideas regarding this. Thanks

```
[2021-04-08 23:36:33,929] -  2021-04-08 23:36:33,929 INFO - b'orchestrator - Previous append blob deleted\n'
[2021-04-08 23:36:33,930] -  2021-04-08 23:36:33,930 INFO - b'orchestrator - Starting data recipe using recipes.recipe-journal-lines-sap\n'
[2021-04-09 01:50:58,705] -  2021-04-09 01:50:58,705 WARNING - State of this instance has been externally set to None. Taking the poison pill.
[2021-04-09 01:50:58,710] - Sending Signals.SIGTERM to GPID 12851
[2021-04-09 01:50:58,710] - Received SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses.
[2021-04-09 01:50:59,399] - Pod Launching failed: Task received SIGTERM signal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator.py", line 251, in execute
    get_logs=self.get_logs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/kubernetes/pod_launcher.py", line 117, in run_pod
    return self._monitor_pod(pod, get_logs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/kubernetes/pod_launcher.py", line 124, in _monitor_pod
    for line in logs:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 808, in __iter__
    for chunk in self.stream(decode_content=True):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 572, in stream
    for line in self.read_chunked(amt, decode_content=decode_content):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 764, in read_chunked
    self._update_chunk_length()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 694, in _update_chunk_length
    line = self._fp.fp.readline()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1071, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 929, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 943, in signal_handler
    raise AirflowException("Task received SIGTERM signal")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Task received SIGTERM signal
```

Comment: Appreciate if anyone have idea on how to solve this as we are getting this issue very frequently. Thanks